# How do you overload the Console.WriteLine() method in C#?

Tags: c#

In C++ I can do the following:

```
Class foo(){
    int x;        
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt);
    ...
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const foo& f)
{
    os << f.x;
    return os;
}

int main(){
    Foo foo1, foo2, foo3;
    std::cout << foo1 << foo2 << foo3;
    return 0;
}
```

Is is possible to do something similar in C#? of do I have to add it as a class function (foo.print());

eg:

```
Foo foo;
Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

Comment: override `Foo`'s `ToString` implementation.

Comment: you should first initialize `foo`  and then override `ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` calls its argument's virtual `ToString` method, so just override it:

```
public class Foo {
    private Int32 x;
    public override String ToString() {
        return this.x.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)